# Python issues with mac: pd.to_csv is breaking the structure of the DF

Tags: python, pandas, macos

In this exercise I am importing a CSV file with pandas.read_csv.

```
training_dataset = pd.read_csv('mi_file.csv', low_memory = False)
```

My file has `print(len(training_dataset))` 902527 lines

Then without doing any changes to my file save it into a new CSV file:

```
training_dataset_1.to_csv('new_file.csv', index = False)
```

When I import again this file and look at the quantity of line of the new dataframe i got 902546 (I have this issue only on MAC, Windows no).

So as my CSV is comma separated I tried to replace all comma from my previous file before exporting to CSV in order to avoid this issue:

```
training_dataset_2 = training_dataset.replace({',': '_'}, regex=True)
```

And then I export my file and upload it again. But when I try to upload this new file I got the following error..
If I divided my file in 3 parts I don't have this issue. How can I make to avoid this issue?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ParserError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-c9a2c4656658> in <module>
----> 1 new_training_dataset_2 = pd.read_csv('/Users/timotheejauffret/Desktop/Rappi/DataAnalisis/Training_Dataset/training_data_spanish_20212501_2.csv',low_memory = False)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
    684     )
    685 
--> 686     return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    687 
    688 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    456 
    457     try:
--> 458         data = parser.read(nrows)
    459     finally:
    460         parser.close()

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
   1184     def read(self, nrows=None):
   1185         nrows = _validate_integer("nrows", nrows)
-> 1186         ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
   1187 
   1188         # May alter columns / col_dict

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
   2143     def read(self, nrows=None):
   2144         try:
-> 2145             data = self._reader.read(nrows)
   2146         except StopIteration:
   2147             if self._first_chunk:

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error()

ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Buffer overflow caught - possible malformed input file.
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why this is happening but have  you tried loading or saving the csv with something other than pandas to avoid the low_memory option? You could try loading with something like:

```
from io import StringIO
import os
strIO = StringIO()
with open(filename, 'rt') as csvfile:
    for line in csvfile:
        strIO.write(line)
strIO.seek(0)
full_df=pd.read_csv(strIO,dtype=str,header=None)
```

(This, by the way would be an efficient way to iteratively load and append a batch of csv's but that's a different topic)

or saving with something like:

```
file = open('df.csv', 'a')
for line in range(len(df)):
    a=[str(i)+', ' for i in df.iloc[line:line+1].values[0]]
    a=''.join(a)[0:-2]
    file.write(a)
```

If you do something like this, you can edit the for loop to hone in on what line is generating the problem and then inspect it to understand why.